# Doubly Linked List in C, showing head pointer values instead of inserted values

Tags: c, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

This is the code for a doubly linked list where the values are inserted at the beginning.
The code keeps returning the head values instead of the actual values.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct Node{
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
    struct Node* prev;
};

struct Node* head;

void InsertatBegin(int a){
    struct Node* NewNode = (struct Node*)(malloc(sizeof(struct Node*)));
    NewNode->data = a;
    NewNode->next = NULL;
    NewNode->prev = NULL;
    if (head == NULL){
        head = NewNode;
        return;
    }
    NewNode->next = head;
    head->prev = NewNode;
    head = NewNode;

}

void traverse(){
    struct Node* temp = head;
    while (temp != NULL) {
    if (temp->next == NULL) {
        printf(" %d->NULL", temp->data);
        }
        else {
            printf(" %d->", temp->data);
        }
        temp = temp->next; // Traversing the List till end
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(){
    head = NULL;
    InsertatBegin(5);
    InsertatBegin(6);
    InsertatBegin(7);
    InsertatBegin(8);
    InsertatBegin(9);
    traverse();

}
```

This is the output for the code, it seems to print the address of the nodes instead of the values stored in the Node.data structure.

```
Output:
        752904464-> 752904448-> 752904432-> 752904416-> 5->NULL
```

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(struct Node*))`-> `malloc(sizeof(struct Node))` you need memory for one object, not a pointer

Comment: Pay close attention to what you allocate: `sizeof(struct Node*) != sizeof(struct Node)`

Answer (score 2):

```
struct Node* NewNode = (struct Node*)(malloc(sizeof(struct Node*)));
```

First step is to remove some excess parentheses!

```
struct Node* NewNode = (struct Node*)malloc( sizeof(struct Node*));
```

Less code makes it easier to spot what may not be correct... So let's fix that.

```
struct Node* NewNode = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
```

You probably shouldn't be "casting" the return from `malloc( )` unless you're using a very old compiler.

```
struct Node* NewNode = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
```

`struct Node` is repeated, and may create a hard-to-find bug if the code is altered carelessly. How much space do we want? Enough to point at with our pointer!

```
struct Node* NewNode = malloc( sizeof *NewNode );
```

Easier to read?

And, wars have been fought over this, but this example shows the benefit of shifting the '*' in the declaration of a pointer.

```
struct Node *NewNode = malloc( sizeof *NewNode );
```

`NewNode` is first-and-foremost a **pointer**. It just happens to be used to point an instance of a "struct Node".

When the struct is declared, one can save even more repetition by using a `typedef` that need not be combined with the declaration

```
struct foo {
    int bar0;
    int bar1;
};
typedef struct foo foo_t; // a conventional naming style
/* or  combined...*/
typedef struct foo {
    int bar0;
    int bar1;
} foo_t;
```

Had a typedef been used, the following would be even more terse

```
Node_t *NewNode = malloc( sizeof *NewNode );
```

Comment: `malloc( sizeof struct Node );`  and `malloc( sizeof  *NewNode );` cannot be compiled in all versions of C. This answer may confuse a beginner.

Comment: @alitayyeb That may be true. The OP didn't mention their development environment, though... This version appears in Q's & A's throughout SO. You'll have quite a task adding this particular caution to all those other items... (Although I'm not keen on getting officious, the front page of {C] does refer to a particular C standard... Opinions may vary...

Comment: @alitayyeb -- `malloc(sizeof struct Node)` is not legal C since `sizeof` operates on either an expression or a parenthesized type: this should be `malloc(sizeof (struct Node))`. Hopefully the poster will correct these parts of the answer. But `malloc(sizeof *NewNode)` is fine because `*NewNode` is an expression, not a type. This is a standard idiom in C which is less verbose, less error-prone, and easier to maintain, e.g., when types change during the lifecycle of a program; guaranteed by the Standard to work.

Comment: @adabsurdum Fixed the "too early" removal of too many parenthesis. Thank you... I was fixated on the destination and didn't pay attention to the legality of the intervening steps... Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you should allocate memory as `Node` not `Node*`.

```c
struct Node* NewNode = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
```

It allocates enough memory for a Node structure and returns a pointer to that allocated memory. You can take a look at this [reference.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc)

Answer (score 0):

you have only one small problem which is this line

`struct Node* NewNode = (struct Node*)(malloc(sizeof(struct Node*)));`

it's supposed to be like this `struct Node* NewNode = (struct Node*)(malloc(sizeof(struct Node)));`

as `sizeof(struct Node*)` will return the size of a pointer and the size of any type of pointer in **c** is mostly 4 bytes , but the size of **Node** is actually 12 bytes not 4 bytes as

> int data; -> 4 bytes
>
> struct Node* next; -> 4bytes
>
> struct Node* prev;  -> 4bytes

,so the total is 12 bytes , actually if you write : `struct Node* NewNode = (struct Node*)(malloc(12));` will actually work, that's what made the error. if the total size of elements of struct called **Node** was 4 bytes like it only has one member whose size is 4 bytes then the statement `sizeof(struct Node)` will have same effect as `sizeof(struct Node*)` which is a correct answer.

and here is the full code edited with image of the output :

```
    #include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
    struct Node* prev;
};

struct Node* head;

void InsertatBegin(int a) {
    struct Node* NewNode = (struct Node*)(malloc(sizeof(struct Node)));
    NewNode->data = a;
    NewNode->next = NULL;
    NewNode->prev = NULL;
    if (head == NULL) {
        head = NewNode;
        return;
    }
    NewNode->next = head;
    head->prev = NewNode;
    head = NewNode;

}

void traverse() {
    struct Node* temp = head;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        if (temp->next == NULL) {
            printf(" %d->NULL", temp->data);
        }
        else {
            printf(" %d->", temp->data);
        }
        temp = temp->next; // Traversing the List till end
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    head = NULL;
    InsertatBegin(5);
    InsertatBegin(6);
    InsertatBegin(7);
    InsertatBegin(8);
    InsertatBegin(9);
    traverse();

}
```

[image]